# Scoping for nested atrributes rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I'm fairly new to Rails. I'm trying to create a voting system where people can vote one answer in a question.

**Question.rb**

```
has_many :choices, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['option'].blank?}, allow_destroy: true

validates_presence_of :title, :user_id
```

**Choice.rb**

```
belongs_to :question
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
```

**Vote.rb**

```
belongs_to :voter, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :choice

validates_presence_of :voter_id, :choice_id
validates_uniqueness_of :voter, scope: :choice
```

Now the scope I have in the "Vote" model only check uniqueness of a choice (I can only vote for that choice once) but I can still vote for other choices in the same question. I would like to be able to vote in a question once. So the question and the choice is unique. I think I need to create a custom scope, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't show your controllers/views or schema I made some assumptions to point you in the right direction.  You can write a custom validation in your Vote.rb model as follows: (Im assuming when you cast a vote it is submitting the user's id, his choice, and the question the choice belongs to.

```
validate :one_vote_per_question

#self is in the 'vote' context so assuming you followed standard rails practices:
def one_vote_per_question
  if Vote.where("voter_id = ? AND question_id = ?", self.voter.id, self.choice.question.id).exists?
     errors.add(:vote, "You have already voted on this question")
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I solved it different but your suggestion definitely pointed me to the right direction. I just created a question_id column for Vote. Then I can just scope the question_id uniqueness.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I think you're missing a quote after the 2nd question mark and before the comma.

Comment: It's there for me.  Should be able to just copy and paste it.